# Null check operator used on a null value FirebaseFirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sort the posts in my application by date, but when I use orderby I get a `null check operator used on a null value` error. The problem is that when I type 'where' together with 'orderby' there is a problem.

My code below:

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('posts')
                      .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid)
                      .orderBy(
                        'datePublished',
                        descending: true,
                      )
                      
                      .snapshots(),
                      
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    return ListView.builder(
                        primary: false,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          DocumentSnapshot snap =
                              (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore is an optimized database. As a result, you have to [create composite indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for complex queries, like the one you are doing (combining `orderBy` with `where`), to work.

To solve this problem, look at the logs where you are running Flutter. you should see a Firebase Console link that will take you straight to creating the query. Create the query, wait for 5 minutes or less for it to build, then try the code again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 more condition

```
if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists

Comment: I think it is if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshot.hasData)

Comment: Try this if ( snapshot.data != null). It would work.

Comment: It didn't work, it's trying to load something and it keeps looping, my posts are not showing up.

Comment: You getting NULL data in snapshot. check this

Comment: When I remove orderby my data comes back

Comment: check 'datePublished' key it may be not contain in every document

Comment: It is successfully happening on the homepage and comments page. It's not just in the profile.

Comment: The problem is that when I write with 'where', there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

because stream can be return null value then snapshot.data! as dynamic make error. Please check snapshot.hasData